# javascript initiated select change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 3 select box with options.
On page reload, I want to have 1st select box with default selected value.
JS Fiddle here:  `http://jsfiddle.net/cqENs/308/`

I did this with following statement and this is working 
 `$("#selone").val("3").change();`

I want to consider this as change event on 1st select box and trigger default selection to be changed in 2nd select box but I was unable to get that.

I want to do this automatically, no manual change events.

Can you help me here.

Comment: So you want the change event to trigger by just changing the value?

Comment: I need change trigger, which I was unable to do, but it is answered, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing `#selone`'s value before you attached a change listener to `#selone`. Move the initial change to the end of your block:

```
$("#selone").on("change", function() {
  $("#seltwo").val("5").change();
});

$("#seltwo").on("change", function() {
  $("#selthr").val("4").change();
});
$("#selone").val("3").change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqENs/309/